# How can I get a list of every item with a unique ID in Minecraft 1.14.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

How can I get a list of every item with a unique ID in Minecraft 1.14.4 in an easy-to-process format? I'm making a data pack that requires a loot table with every item, and it would take much too long to manually type in ~900 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a JSON list ([Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Zgst4gZx)).

I ran this script on the [Blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block#List_of_blocks) page on the wiki:

```
const table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]
const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr')
const blocks = [...rows]
  .map(r => {
    const as = r.getElementsByTagName('a')
    return as.length === 1 ? as[0] : as[1]
  })
  .map(a => a.textContent.replace(/'| /g, '_').toLowerCase())
```

and this one on the [Items](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item#List_of_items) page:

```
const items = uls.reduce((ids, ul) => {
  [...ul.children]
    .map(li => li.children[1].textContent.replace(/'| /g, '_').toLowerCase())
    .forEach(i => ids.push(i))
  return ids
}, [])
```

**Disclaimer:** The script just converted the names to snake_case and I haven't double-checked them, so some of them may be wrong.